# Calculate Scaling Into Collision Detection

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have been messing around in Monogame while I teach myself c#. I followed Microsofts XNA tutorial for detecting collision in a 2d. [Here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/collision)

In what I have done in Monogame so far is very very basic. There are 2 sprites. A player and a coal texture. The coal appears in a random spot when you start the game and you can move the player around. I have scaled up my textures.

The Microsoft tutorial doesn't deal with scaling and I was wondering if there was a way to get the amount I scaled the texture by into the collision detection method.

Here is my code.

This is the Game1 class. The collision detection method is at the bottom.

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using System.Diagnostics;
#endregion

namespace Supersum
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Player player;
    Coal coal;
    Random random;

    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
    KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;

    GamePadState currentGamePadState;
    GamePadState previousGamePadState;


    float playerMoveSpeed;

    public Game1()
        : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        player = new Player();
        coal = new Coal();
        random = new Random();


        playerMoveSpeed = 8.0f;

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
        Vector2 coalPosition = new Vector2(random.Next(800), random.Next(480));
        player.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("tempChar"), playerPosition);
        coal.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Coal"), coalPosition);



    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();


        previousGamePadState = currentGamePadState;
        previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;

        currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        currentGamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);


        UpdatePlayer(gameTime);
        UpdateCollision();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointWrap, null, null, null);

        coal.Draw(spriteBatch);
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)||currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            player.Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)||currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            player.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)||currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            player.Position.Y -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)||currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            player.Position.Y += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCollision()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle1;
        Rectangle rectangle2;

        rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Width * 2, player.Height * 2);
        rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)coal.Position.X, (int)coal.Position.Y, coal.Width * 4, coal.Height * 4);

        if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2))
        {
            Console.Write("Intersected\n");
        }
        else {
            Console.Write("Not Intersected\n");
        }

    }
}
}
```

And these are my classes for my player and coal.

Player

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Supersum
{
class Player
{
    public Texture2D PlayerTexture;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public bool Active;
    public int Health;

    public int Width
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Height; }
    }

    public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        PlayerTexture = texture;
        Position = position;
        Active = true;
        Health = 100;
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 2f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
 }
}
```

And now Coal

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Supersum
{
class Coal
{
    public Texture2D coalTexture;
    public Vector2 Position;

    public int Width
    {
        get { return coalTexture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return coalTexture.Height; }
    }

    public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        coalTexture = texture;
        Position = position;
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(coalTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 4f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `amount I scaled the texture by`? In your code I don't see any kind of `scale` variable. If you scaled the textures yourself, then your code should still work.

Comment: Do you just mean making the `2` and `4` that you're multiplying with the Player's and Coal's `Width` and `Height` into `scale` variables?

Comment: In the player and coal class the Draw method has a property for scaling. Right before Sprite effects. In player it's 2f so it's scaled up 2X and in coal it's 4f so it's scaled up 4X.

Comment: Please add that to your code then.

Comment: They are already in there. Maybe I am not explaing what I'm trying to do well enough.

Comment: I want to make it so that instead of having to type in what I am scaling the textures by in my collision method I just multiply by the scale.

Like right now it is player.Width X 2. I want to see if I can make it player.Width * Scale. I am just not sure how to get the scale property from the Draw method in my player and coal classes.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding them why don't you simply make a private field and use that for both Draw and multiplying width/height? I don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: It's a little odd to scale your game objects (player, coal). An alternative is to always work with unscaled objects and only scale the drawing and input code. This way, you only have to think about scaling in 2 places in your code. I wrote a short blog post about how I do it here: http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/monogame-code-snippets/monogame-resolution-independence/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a private field for your scaling and use it in both Draw and Height/Width. That way you won't have to use any scaling at all in your collision detection

```
class Coal
{
    public Texture2D coalTexture;
    public Vector2 Position;
    private float scale = 4f;

    public int Width
    {
        get { return coalTexture.Width * scale; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return coalTexture.Height * scale; }
    }

    [...]

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(coalTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
```

---

If they are prone to change and/or used at multiple places (Usually there's a lot of tweaking involved when making a game), you can also make a static class containing all your scales :

```
public static class ScaleConstants
{
    public static float Player = 2f;
    public static float Coal = 4f;
}
```

Which would change the calls from (for example) `return coalTexture.Width * scale;` to `return coalTexture.Width * ScaleConstants.Coal;`

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure why I didn't think of this before. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode your scales.

You should add a `float scale;` to both `class Player` and `class Coal`, and then simply use that member in all of the places that you are currently using the scales `2` and `4`.